# Multithreading design-pattern

Tags: c#, multithreading, design-patterns

While keeping in mind that:

- I am using a blocking queue that waits for ever until something is added to it
- I might get a FileSystemWatcher event twice

The **updated** code:

```
 {
        FileProcessingManager processingManager = new FileProcessingManager();
        processingManager.RegisterProcessor(new ExcelFileProcessor());
        processingManager.RegisterProcessor(new PdfFileProcessor());
        processingManager.Completed += new ProcessingCompletedHandler(ProcessingCompletedHandler);
        processingManager.Completed += new ProcessingCompletedHandler(LogFileStatus);
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var jobData = (JobData)fileMonitor.FileQueue.Dequeue();
                if (jobData == null)
                    break;

                _pool.WaitOne();
                Application.Log(String.Format("{0}:{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), "Thread launched"));
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => processingManager.Process(jobData));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Application.Log(String.Format("{0}:{1}", DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), e.Message));
            }
        }
    }
```

What are are you suggestions on making the code multi-threaded while taking into consideration the possibility that two identical string paths may be added into the blocking queue? I have left the possibility that this might happen and in this case.. the file would be processed twice, the thing is that sometimes I get it twice, sometimes not, it is really awkward, if you have suggestions on this, please tell.

The null checking is for exiting the loop, I intentionally add a null from outside the threaded loop to determine it to stop.

Comment: Can you deduplicate the queue?  What kind of paths are you expecting? If you are processing all files in a several directories then you could do a thread per directory kind of thing.

Comment: When you get the alert, can you first move the file to a subfolder?  If the move is successful, then add it to the queue.  Since a file can only be moved once from A to B, this should prevent duplicates.

Comment: file paths, within a single directory, not more. i don t know if deduplication might help me because when the Second Event would arrive the first notification might as well be popped from the queue so the second notification would be unique at that time in the queue

Comment: @mbeckish your idea is interesting, but doesn t this add a lot of overhead, considering for example very large files?

Comment: @A.K - You could do some other atomic operation, like adding a record to a database table, create an empty "lock" file, etc.

Comment: I think the name ThreadProc is misleading because in old patterns that means the actual kernel of the thread. But here it is the place where you will spawn threads/Tasks.

Comment: @A.K - no. A file move, within one disk, is not a copy.  The OS just moves the file metadata from one directory to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multi-threading this... I would probably add a "Completed" event to your FileProcessingManager and register for it. One argument of that event will be the "bool" return value you currently have. Then in that event handler, I would do the checking of the bool and re-queueing of the file. Note that you will have to keep a reference to the FileMonitorManager. So, I would have this ThreadProc method be in a class where you keep the FileMonitorManager and FileProcessingManager instances in a property.

To deduplicate, in ThreadProc, I would create a List outside of the while loop. Then inside the while loop, before you process a file, lock that list, check to see if the string is already in there, if not, add the string to the list and process the file, if it is, then skip processing.

Obviously, this is based on little information surrounding your method but my 2 cents anyway.

Rough code, from Notepad:

```
private static FileMonitorManager fileMon = null;
private static FileProcessingManager processingManager = new FileProcessingManager();

private static void ThreadProc(object param)
{
    processingManager.RegisterProcessor(new ExcelFileProcessor());
    processingManager.RegisterProcessor(new PdfFileProcessor());
    processingManager.Completed += ProcessingCompletedHandler;
    var procList = new List<string>();

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            var path = (string)fileMon.FileQueue.Dequeue();
            if (path == null)
                break;

            bool processThis = false;
            lock(procList)
            {
                if(!procList.Contains(path))
                {
                    processThis = true;
                    procList.Add(path);
                }
            }
            if(processThis)
            {
                Thread t = new Thread (new ParameterizedThreadStart(processingManager.Process));
                t.Start (path);
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}

private static void ProcessingCompletedHandler(bool status, string path)
{
    if (!status)
    {
        fileMon.FileQueue.Enqueue(path);
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nError on file: " + path);
    }
    else
        Console.WriteLine("\n\nSucces on file: " + path);
}
```

Comment: Another question, I'm new to events in c#, new to c# actually, just read about them, shouldn't the ProcessingCompletedHandler be called somewhere? sorry if I 'm mistaken.

Comment: From what I understand this event handling thing just lets you call a function defined outside of your class from within your class.. so there must be a function call.

Comment: You can do the event through delegates in C#. [Here](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html) is an article explaining delegates, going from simple to more complex use cases. In your case, you'll define a delegate in your FileProcessingManager and an event. Then inside it's Process method, you would raise the event. See the example under the heading "Multicasting" and "Events" in that link.

Comment: I'd change the pattern in a way that the processors would register to the ProcessingCompletedHandler, and it supposed to be called at the end of processing. I'd put it into some common Base class for the Processors.

Comment: @CsabaToth can you elaborate? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: The main thing is that the main "conductor" portion of your program, which spawns the threads should know what files are currently processed. This way the "conductor" can avoid "collision" (processing a file by more threads at the same time).

Comment: Gotcha. Since the OP didn't provide that portion, I assumed that the processor has no control over that code. If he has control, I agree that the filtering of duplicates should happen up front.

Comment: I'd also examine/debug more why the FileWatcher sends multiple messages, maybe with some logic you can filter them out easily. But even after that make your code robust to handle such situations.

Comment: Tombala's suggestion points to a direction how the central portion of your code keep track of the currently processed files. I'd look into Task parallel techniques, Task class in general.

Comment: I have done like you suggested, and works nicely - what about multithreading it now?

Comment: All good, design is great, works ok, now multithreading it using TPL .. the thing is that I want it to allow a maximum of n threads running at the same time

Comment: And I think I'll use a semaphore object that blocks just before the TASK.factory.startnew =>  processingManager.Process(path)

Comment: Limiting the thread pool size seems to be a little tricky with TPL. [See this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351)